# How to estimate the noise variance of covSEiso covariance function for GPML code?

Tags: gaussian-process

For the covariance function `covSEiso`:

$$k(x^i,x^j)=\sigma_f^2\exp(-(x^i-x^j)^T{\rm diag}(l)^{-2}(x^i-x^j))+\sigma_n^2\delta_{ij}$$

in `GPML` Matlab package, there are three types of hyper parameters, $(\sigma_f, l, \sigma_n)$. The code seems to optimize only $(\sigma_f, l)$. Would you please let me know how to estimate $\sigma_n$? Do I need to assume this value? If so, how can I incorporate this assumed value into the `covSEiso` function?

Comment: Are you only asking how the MATLAB code works / what code to use, or are you asking how this function is estimated more generally? Note that if it is the former, the question would be off-topic here, but could be on-topic on [SO] (it would help if you could add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), though). If the latter, can you add more context about this function, what it is & where it's used?

Answer (score 1):

I agree it is off-topic, nevertheless the answer is simple. This parameter is a hyperparameter of the Gauss-likelihood. See lines 19 and 20 of usageLik.m:

`sn = 0.1;                                % noise standard deviation
lr0 = {'likGauss'};   hypr0 = log(sn);`

or the usage example they give on their page in Section 4 subsection 3a) (sic!) "Regression"
The estimation works then in exactly the same way as for the other parameters.

Comment: I am sorry for posting the off the topic question and thank you for your reply. Then, it seems that the noise level is not an target for optimization. It seems to work as a kind of complexity parameter we need to determine through cross-validation. It is separate question. In general, to estimate the noise variance, do we need the response data for the same input? Otherwise, how we can compute the noise variance?

Comment: As I said, the noise level IS included in the maximum likelihood calculation.

Comment: I mean the noise level is included in the maximum likelihood calculation, but is not the target of optimization. I read the whole section about the model selection in the book of Gaussian Process for machine learning by Rasmussen and Williams, but the selection procedure for the noise variance is not explained.

Comment: Maybe there is a confusion of terms. The maximum likelihood calculation does involve optimisation. The noise variance is, among other hyperparameters, chosen to maximise the likelihood. Are you looking for a different optimisation?

Comment: The maximum likelihood calculation involves the noise variance term sn. But the noise variance is first initialized as a constant before starting optimization. Assuming the noise variance is fixed as constant as "sn", the optimization proceeds to find optimum length scales of the kernel function. The code only provides the optimized length scales and the signal variance, but does not provides the optimized noise variance. Have you tried to optimize or determine the noise variance from the training data?

Comment: But this is not true! Why do you think so? Did you have a look at the demo? In file demoRegression.m line 68 the noise parameter is initialised in line 74 the resulting value after optimisation displayed. Run the demo and observe that the values are different.